# Why the parallelized fortran code takes longer to run?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have been trying to parallelize a subroutine of my 2D FEM code, which basically performs a matrix multiplication at each time step, in order to calculate the mass, internal forces and gravity at each integration point. I have been trying many options on how to reduce the running time by parallelizing but always the parallelized code takes longer than the regular one.

Can somebody please give me an idea why this happens in my case?

Thank you

(attached you can find the subroutine)

```
subroutine Map2Nod()

!**********************************************************************
!    Function: Internal and External Forces, Mass at each nodes
!**********************************************************************
implicit none
integer :: I, IEl, Id, INod(4), ig, J

GrvF = 0.D0; InrF = 0.D0; ExtF = 0.D0; Mas = 0.D0

ExtF(2) = -50
ExtF(4) = -50


!$omp parallel do private(iel,ig,i,id,inod) 

do iel = 1, nel
    inod(:) = icon(:, iel)
    do ig = 1, 4
        do i = 1, 4
            id = (inod(i) - 1) * 2
            inrf(id + 1) = inrf(id + 1)+(sigg(1,ig,iel) * b(1,i,iel,ig) + sigg(4,ig,iel) * b(2, i, iel, ig)) * area(iel)/4.d0
            inrf(id + 2) = inrf(id + 2)+(sigg(4,ig,iel) * b(1,i,iel,ig) + sigg(2,ig,iel) * b(2, i, iel, ig)) * area(iel)/4.d0
            grvf(id + 1) = grvf(id + 1) + area(iel) * matprop(3) * hs(i, iel, ig) * gx /4.d0
            grvf(id + 2) = grvf(id + 2) + area(iel) * matprop(3) * hs(i, iel, ig) * gy /4.d0
            mas(id + 1) = mas(id + 1) + area(iel) * matprop(3) * hs(i, iel, ig) /4.d0
            mas(id + 2) = mas(id + 2) + area(iel) * matprop(3) * hs(i, iel, ig) /4.d0
        end do
    enddo !gauss
end do !nel 

!$omp end parallel do

end subroutine Map2Nod
```

Comment: How do you measure the time? Please make a full short program we can test and paste here. Tell us what is `nel` and where does it come from in the subroutine. Is the subroutine in a module? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Indirect indexing raises possible false sharing, no conclusion possible without full reproducer.

Comment: @tim18, its's worse than false sharing. There could easily be true sharing causing race conditions here too. (Multiple threads could be trying to accumulate into the same elements simultaneously).